# How can I glue behind my tub surround without removing it?

Tags: bathroom, adhesive

Tub surround is from an old installation and has to be at least 14 years old. Which is as long as we have owned the house. While getting ready to re-caulk the tub we found that the tub surround is pulling away from the drywall behind it. The highest is over a foot from the tub up the wall. That is from the middle of the tub/wall horizontally. Near the edges it appears fine.

We can pull on the surround enough to be able to see a little behind. The drywall behind looks great. I see no water damage. We plan on renovating the bathroom within the next two years... but *not now*. Removing the tub surround partition that needs the most significant gluing seems very risky as it feels like it might crack the tub surround if we pull on it too much and that would make for a way worse situation

I wanted to see if there was a way to get enough glue behind to get some minor adhesion. I attached foot and half length of 1/4 inch vinyl hose to a pl premium tube with pull ties. Tried to see if I could force product through. That failed after about 6 inches as the force pushed the tube off.

[image: Tub surround with text]

<sup>Click image to embiggen</sup>

Worst case is we are going to try and use a small putty knife to get the bottom couple of inches covered and hope for the best.

Comment: I'm missing something crucial here. Why do you think it's necessary to glue the surround down perfectly at this point? Can't you just caulk around the tub and call it a day? It's not like the surround would be expected to carry any loads, and the caulk itself should do a good enough job of gluing stuff together, shouldn't it? I mean, given than you just need it to hold for two years.

Comment: @TooTea The tub surround is hanging slightly in front of the wall... there is empty space there so fi I caulk it up there will be an air bubble of sorts in there. It doesnt take much to move that so an errant hand or my kids goofing around are able to move it slightly. Any movement has the potential to break the caulk seal and then its all for not.

Comment: I bet a couple quick shots of 'Great Stuff' would do the trick for you.  It comes with a long thin flexible tube, so easy to get up behind the panel.   The material is super sticky and will hold it for sure.  It expands so it'll fill alotta area and get up further than the straw alone does.  The trick is not to use too much.  If you did, the panel would protrude out.   Definitely experiment on some similar scrap pieces before committing.  A little of this stuff goes a long way.